# windows7 64bit python pip install error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, installation

I tried all the methods that I can find online and I even dove into the python code it didn't help.

I am using windows 7 64 bit version. I have installed Microsoft VS 2008 and 2012 both. The Python I installed is 3.5

When I run pip install numpy, I am getting error:

> Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

The version return by the code in `msvc9compiler.py` shows my VS version is 14.0 and I dive into all kinds of windows registry to add a couple of entries(VC and ProdctDir to point to the VS 2008 VC folder). It didn't help. I can run `vcvarsall.bat` from the command line and it runs fine with following result.
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.

I though it works fine.

Is there anything else I can try?  I have spent two days on this.

Comment: Python 3.5 requires [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to this : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350a1/
python 3.5 is compiled with vs2015.

if you done want to install vs2015 you can set the enviroment variable VS__COMNTOOLS where __ is the version number of visual studio. for example in python 2.7 i had to do this in cmd before using pip

```
SET VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
```

im not sure but i think the version number of vs2015  is 13
so do

```
SET VS130COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
```

or you can do

```
SET VS130COMNTOOLS=%VS10COMNTOOLS%
```

Comment: I have two places for vcvarsall.bat C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC  These are for VS 2008 and VS 2012. Are you positive that I need to install VS 2015 for Python 3.5?

Comment: Put the one of the newer visual Studio version

Comment: I downloaded and installed VS 2015 from Microsoft. There is a new environment variable created VS140COMNTOOLS the value is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\   One thing I don't get it is I didn't see the compiler vcvarsall.bat in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC  It's still not working. I am getting same error.

Comment: I missed some component when I run the installation. Now I added Visual C++ tool box and the compiler showed up. When I run pip install numpy, I am getting different error now. Tried to install other packages, each one has different error.  Such as ValueError SyntaxError. Maybe pip downloaded a version for Python 2.7?

Comment: Can you add the errors so we can see what's happening?

Comment: I gave  up on python 3.5. Installed 2.7 and everything works fine now. thank you for the help though.

Comment: Lots of us stuck at the same place as you frank...  were you able to resolve this? No idea why MS / Python would not create an easy approach to this.

Answer (score 5):

Bonson, Frank, etc.

Re-install or upgrade Visual Studio 2015 Community and make sure you select Visual C++ then proceed. It worked for me on Windows 7 64bit with Python 3.5.1 which I installed as part of WinPython 3.5.1.2 64bit.

[image: Visual C++]

See also: [vcvarsall.bat needed for python to compile missing from visual studio 2015 ( v 14)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323172/vcvarsall-bat-needed-for-python-to-compile-missing-from-visual-studio-2015-v-1)