# python 3.5 scikit-learn developer version error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat VS 2015

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.5

I need to install the latest version of scikit-learn, so i use version from GitHub with command

```
python setup.py install --user
```

instead of compiled version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn

and have this error

```
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from
    distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_clib
    building 'libsvm-skl' library
    compiling C sources
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Also solution using MinGW doesn't work ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838827/3618344)) with exception

`ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900`

The same exeption throws when I try to install from VS command promt

Solution with

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

also throws the same exception with vcvarsall.bat

Also installng C++ Common Tools doesn't help ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243904/3618344))

Setting

```
SET VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools
```

have the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is connected with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243904/3618344), my fault was that I downloaded [C++ Common Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=48145)  as a separate package, but you need to reinstall VS and select "Common Tools For Visual Studio 2015"