# Unable to install the python module aubio from github, or from pip

Tags: python, audio, module, pip

For pip:

In my command prompt I type in:

```
C:/Python/Scripts/pip install aubio
```

Recommended by this site:

http://aubio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_module.html

And get this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPsI4.jpg

It was suggested that I download a C++ compiler for Python, but doing so hasn't prevented the error.

So I tried installing the module via github.

For Github via pip:

I naturally installed Github and went back to my command prompt.

I typed in:

```
C:/Python/Scripts/pip install git+git://git.aubio.org/git/aubio
```

And when that failed:

```
C:/Python/Scripts/pip install git+git://git.aubio.org/git/aubio.git
```

I get the error:

```
 Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing c
ommand git clone -q git://github.com/aubio/aubio.git C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-ornio5sm-build
Cannot find command 'git'
```

A lot of the other questions had answers concerning a broken setup file, but I'm not entirely sure how I check for that.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323172/vcvarsall-bat-needed-for-python-to-compile-missing-from-visual-studio-2015-v-1

Also from their site http://aubio.org/news/20160522-1500_pip.html
it looks like aubio depends on something that comes with Visual studio 2008 mainly `vcvarsall.bat`. As a side note, for your git command to work, you will need git the program itself https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't the whole answer, but it will help anyone who comes here in the future.

I installed Github and not git. That's why the git command isn't recognized.

The correct place for installation[WINDOWS] is: https://git-for-windows.github.io/