# Using Python 3.5 to get Speaker Volume

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, volume

I'm using the volume button on my headset as sort of an external controller so all I need to do get get the volume that my Windows computer is set to. How would I do that?

I have tried `alsaautio` but I can't get it to install on windows. Here's what the command prompt says when I try to `python setup.py build`:

```
alsaaudio.c(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'alsa/asoundlib.h': No such file or directory
```

Is there any other way I can get my computer's volume?

Comment: `vcvarsall.bat` is part of Visual Studio's installation. It sets up the environment for compiling Visual Studio-produced code.

Comment: What version of Python is this? Potentially [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266) can fix the issue for Python 2.7 without having to download all of Visual Studio.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm using Python 3.5 32 bit

Comment: @kenWhite I also have Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Then the path is not configured correctly for your script to locate it (thus the *Unable to find*). Or it's looking for a specific version of VS, and is looking for a specific location for the file and it's not there.

Comment: @kenWhite how can I fix that? I'm searching my PC for any files named `vcvarsall.bat`. My file explorer just said that there is no file called 'vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: As I said, it's part of Visual Studio. It should be located somewhere within the VS folder tree. If it's not there, you don't have a full installation of VS. Have you read the instructions for building the project to see what's required?

Comment: Maybe this can help @GriffinM., [Using vcvarsall.bat in a Command Prompt window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: @downshift I tried that and it returned: `PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC> vcvarsall
vcvarsall : The term 'vcvarsall' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: @GriffinM. ok, your prompt shows `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>` which is the directory that should contain `vcvarsall.bat`. At that same prompt, run the command `dir` and see if `vcvarsall.bat` is in the list? If you don't see the `vcvarsall.bat` file, you might need to [Make sure C++ Common Tools are installed in Visual Studio.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323172/vcvarsall-bat-needed-for-python-to-compile-missing-from-visual-studio-2015-v-1)

Comment: @downshift Ok, I tried searching and there is no vcvarsall.bat so I'm installing it with Microsoft Visual Studio...

Comment: @GriffinM., ok cool let us know how it goes

Comment: vcvarsall.bat is in the dir, thanks @downshift