# Errors installing scipy/cython/numpy/jupyter on python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, cython, python-3.8

I just installed python 3.8 (windows server 2016) and I was experiencing errors installing scipy with pip install I thought it might be related to cython so I tried to install it but got the same error. Is there a certain package I should install to make this work with python 3.8? 
(similar errors for jupyter/numpy)
These packages are installed with python 3.7.2 on my computer without having C++ 14
error:

````
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\winuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\winuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-req-build-x4ml1lce\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\winuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-req-build-x4ml1lce\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\winuser\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-p26khif7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\winuser\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-req-build-x4ml1lce\
    Complete output (287 lines):
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\Coverage.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\Debugging.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\Shadow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\StringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\TestUtils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    copying Cython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    copying Cython\Build\BuildExecutable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    copying Cython\Build\Cythonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    copying Cython\Build\Dependencies.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    copying Cython\Build\Distutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    copying Cython\Build\Inline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    copying Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    copying Cython\Build\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\AnalysedTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Annotate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\AutoDocTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Buffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Builtin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\CmdLine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Code.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\CodeGeneration.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\CythonScope.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\DebugFlags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\ExprNodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Future.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Interpreter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Lexicon.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\MemoryView.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\ModuleNode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Naming.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Optimize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\PyrexTypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Pythran.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\StringEncoding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\TreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\TreePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\TypeInference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\TypeSlots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\UtilityCode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\UtilNodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Runtime
    copying Cython\Runtime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Runtime
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
    copying Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
    copying Cython\Distutils\extension.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
    copying Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
    copying Cython\Distutils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Distutils
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
    copying Cython\Debugger\Cygdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
    copying Cython\Debugger\DebugWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
    copying Cython\Debugger\libcython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
    copying Cython\Debugger\libpython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
    copying Cython\Debugger\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\TestLibCython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libcython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libpython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Actions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\DFA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Lexicons.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Machines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Regexps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Transitions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
    copying Cython\Tests\TestCodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
    copying Cython\Tests\TestCythonUtils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
    copying Cython\Tests\TestJediTyper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
    copying Cython\Tests\TestStringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
    copying Cython\Tests\xmlrunner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
    copying Cython\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
    copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestCyCache.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
    copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestCythonizeArgsParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
    copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestInline.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
    copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestIpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
    copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestStripLiterals.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
    copying Cython\Build\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestBuffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestCmdLine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestFlowControl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestGrammar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestMemView.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestSignatureMatching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTypes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestUtilityLoad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestVisitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
    copying Cython\Tempita\compat3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
    copying Cython\Tempita\_looper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
    copying Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
    copying Cython\Tempita\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Tempita
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
    copying pyximport\pyxbuild.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
    copying pyximport\pyximport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
    copying pyximport\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyximport
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes
    copying Cython\Includes\openmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\array.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytearray.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ceval.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\datetime.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\descr.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\longintrepr.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\memoryview.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pylifecycle.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pyport.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pystate.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pythread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\slice.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\locale.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\setjmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\stddef.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdint.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    copying Cython\Includes\libc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\algorithm.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\cast.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\deque.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\forward_list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\functional.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\pair.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\queue.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\stack.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeindex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\utility.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\vector.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
    copying Cython\Includes\numpy\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
    copying Cython\Includes\numpy\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\dlfcn.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\fcntl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\ioctl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\mman.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\resource.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\select.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\stat.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\strings.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\types.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\unistd.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\wait.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Includes\posix\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
    copying Cython\Compiler\Code.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Compiler
    copying Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Runtime
    copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\codefile -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\cfuncs.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    copying Cython\Plex\Actions.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Plex
    copying Cython\Utility\CConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\CpdefEnums.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\CppConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\TestCythonScope.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\TestCyUtilityLoader.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\AsyncGen.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Buffer.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Builtins.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Capsule.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\CMath.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\CommonStructures.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Complex.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Coroutine.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\CythonFunction.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Embed.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Exceptions.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\ExtensionTypes.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\FunctionArguments.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\ImportExport.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView_C.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\ModuleSetupCode.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\ObjectHandling.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Optimize.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Overflow.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Printing.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\Profile.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\StringTools.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\TestUtilityLoader.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
    running build_ext
    building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\winuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\winuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-req-build-x4ml1lce\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\winuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-req-build-x4ml1lce\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\winuser\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-p26khif7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output. ```
````

Comment: It says: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/` Have you tried to install it?

Comment: Another URL for @Thom's comment. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Im able to install these packages on the same server with python 3.7.2. so I am not sure the root cause here is lack of  C++ 14.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vcvarsall.bat needed for python to compile missing from visual studio 2015 ( v 14)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323172/vcvarsall-bat-needed-for-python-to-compile-missing-from-visual-studio-2015-v-1)

Comment: why would it work with python 3.7.2 and not with python 3.8?